# What is the origin of the phrase "I'll take a raincheck"?

Tags: phrases, etymology, american-english, nouns

What is the origin of the phrase *I'll take a raincheck*?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The literal sense of rain check, which is an Americanism, is first found in the 1880s in reference to a baseball game. The practice of giving a rain check to a ticketholder was formalized in 1890 in the constitution of the National League. In other words, if it rained (something the purchaser had no influence over) and the game was postponed, the ticket holder could come back for another game.

Comment: Hmm, so if someone say "*I'll take a raincheck on the drink tonight*", is the correct reply to say "*I hope it rains then*", or "*I hope it doesn't rain then*"?

Comment: @Pacerier Neither.  Some correct responses could be "That's ok.  We'll do it another time." or "Sure.  Let me know when you're free next."   The implication of a "rain check" is that they couldn't make it because of an event beyond their control.

Comment: If you take a rain check, it has already rained.

Answer (score 13):

> **[rain check:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rain_check)** *(idiomatic)* In social interactions, a polite way to
>   turn down an invitation, with the
>   implication one is simply postponing
>   it and that another time would be
>   acceptable.
>
> *I can't go with you to the museum this Saturday, but can I take a rain
>   check and go some other day?*
>
> **Etymology**:
>
> The expression may have originated in
>   the era of open-air markets where the
>   occurrence of significant rain usually
>   required a vendor to pack up their
>   goods and leave. The term may also be
>   based on the issuing of tickets to
>   claim property such as a coat or hat
>   check. Before 1889, US baseball fans
>   were issued a new ticket if rain was
>   heavy enough to cause a game to be
>   postponed. Abner Powell added a
>   detachable stub called a rain check
>   that year. This quickly became a
>   standard practice for all major league
>   teams.

---

> **[rain check (on something):](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rain+check)**
>
> **a reissuance of an invitation at a later date.** (Said to someone who has
>   invited you to something that you
>   cannot attend now, but would like to
>   attend at a later time. *Typically:
>   get ~; have ~; take ~; give someone
>   ~.)
>
> *We would love to come to your house, but we are busy next Saturday. Could
>   we take a rain check on your kind
>   invitation? Oh, yes. You have a rain
>   check that's good anytime you can come
>   by and visit.*

Answer (score 3):

NOAD reports:

> rain check (also raincheck)
>   noun
>   A ticket given for later use when a sports event or other outdoor event is interrupted or postponed by rain.
>   • A coupon issued to a customer by a store, guaranteeing that a sale item that is out of stock may be purchased by that customer at a later date at the same reduced price.
>
> **PHRASES**
>   *Take a rain check*—said when politely refusing an offer, with the implication that one may accept it at a later date: *I can’t make it tonight, but I’d like to take a rain check*.